# Why is the probability of pulling a blue marble on the third try independent of how many blue marbles we pull on the second or first- no-replacements?

Tags: probability, independence

> A bag contains 10 identically-shaped marbles: 3 red, 4 blue, and 3 green. A person randomly pulls out the marbles one by one (without replacement).

What is the probability of pulling a blue marble on the 3rd try?

The answer is 4/10. I don't think that's right because what if were to pull blue on the first try or second try? Then my intuition says we have $<\dfrac{4}{10}$ on the 3rd try.

I don't think the subsequent draws are independent of the previous draws.

Comment: Nobody said it was independent of those draws.  But you don't know anything about them and, at the start, each ball is likely to be drawn at any particular moment.

Comment: Think of it this way: Suppose you only had two marbles, one white and one black.  Convince yourself that the second one you draw has a $\frac 12$ of being black.  Again, the two draws are obviously dependent.

Comment: "[W]hat if we were to pull blue on the first try or second try? Then my intuition says we have $< \frac{4}{10}$ on the 3rd try." **Exactly correct!** However, what if you *don't* draw a blue marble on your first or second tries? Your probability then *increases* for the 3rd try. When you consider all the possibilities in aggregate of what could happen on the first 2 tries, they balance out in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two explanations.

1. Suppose you imagine that someone has taken the marbles from the bag one at a time and arranged them in a line. Then the chance that the fourth marble is blue is clearly just $4/10$. That calculation does not depend on  the colors of the marbles in the first three places.
2. You are correct in asserting that the appearance of a blue marble on the fourth draw does indeed depend on what happens in the first three. That said, if you do the ugly conditional probability calculations you end up with $4/10$.

   I'll just do it for the second marble being blue. That probability is $3/9$ if the first marble is blue and $4/9$ if it's not. The probability that the first marble is blue is $4/10$. So the probability that the second is blue is
   $$
   \frac{4}{10}\frac{3}{9} + \frac{6}{10}\frac{4}{9} = \frac{4}{10} \ .
   $$

Check out [linearity of expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/).